# How to write a scrollDown method which works on any size of mobile screen?

Tags: java, testing, mobile, android-testing

I wrote test script for android mobile testing in java and test on 5.5 inch kit-kat android device. But when I am testing in on different screen size I got errors because the elements scrolls up or down.Scroll method works fine with 5.5 but not with 5.0 screen size. Can anyone help me out I am new to programming.
I use this Code:

```
public static void verticalScroll(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) throws Throwable {
    try {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int y_start = (int) (size.height * 0.60);
        int y_end = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
        int x = size.width / 2;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.swipe(x, y_start, x, y_end, 3000);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not about the screen size, is about the kind of control in which you are trying to do the swiping (and may be something about the Android versión in the different devices in which you are trying).
There are controls that already use the swipe, so if you want to swipe an element inside those controls you have to handle the spread.

Comment: I wrote a swipedown method to click on a particular element. It works fine in 5.5 inch screen but when I test it on 5 inch screen that scroll up more and the element gone. So it couldnt find that element.